# Shapefiles are not being added to MXD using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, shapefile, mxd

I want to add a shapefile to an mxd document using arcpy but it generates the following error when used by adding script in arctoolbox

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0] 
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:/Data/input/Line.shp")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame, addLayer)
```

*ERROR--------------*

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source
Failed to execute (Script).
```

Comment: Are you sure that D:/Data/input/Line.shp exists? Have you tried addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'D:/Data/input/Line.shp')?

Comment: yes file exist and single cote also not work

Comment: Your drive is "D" and not "C"?  Can you try to load a different shapefile?  Are you current on your service packs?

Comment: yes service packs are ok - lyr file work fine but shp file generates error

Answer (score 3):

I tested your snippet (at least in ArcMap's interactive Python window) and got the same error until I changed the formatting of the string parameter to the Layer() method. Either single or double quotes work, but I had to use forward slashes, not backslashes, and no leading 'r'. Like:

```
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer('C:/path/to/shapefile.shp')
```

or

```
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:/path/to/shapefile.shp")
```

Comment: thanks , but code not work for shp file for lyr it works and i used extra function of arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management to convert shp to lyr . now it works for me

Comment: no, I know the API examples show use of *.lyr file, but what I show above most definitely works with a shapefile or other data source, I took your snippet exactly and only modified the string argument as shown and it ran successfully.

Comment: thanks anyway but not working for me, and i donot the reason

Answer (score 0):

You need add into argument of Layer class the "lyr_file_path".
Layer() class accepts *.lyr file!

Can you try with layer (*.lyr) file?

Comment: yes it works for lyr